'LlamaConfig' object has no attribute 'quantization_config'
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-19-c4c94986d254> in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 model.config.quantization_config.to_dict()

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/transformers/configuration_utils.py in __getattribute__(self, key)
    259         if key != "attribute_map" and key in super().__getattribute__("attribute_map"):
    260             key = super().__getattribute__("attribute_map")[key]
--> 261         return super().__getattribute__(key)
    262 
    263     def __init__(self, **kwargs):

AttributeError: 'LlamaConfig' object has no attribute 'quantization_config'

I'm using google colab with t4 gpu please help
I thought it was a problem with the version so pip installed a newer one, that didnt work, also tried uninstalling and installing that didn't help either. I also tried changing runtime to cpu.

post the code that you try to run and the whole error stack here.
